# Count users who have 2 specific milestone values in their records

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a progress table with a log of milestone events in a user's history.

Table fields:

```
id(int), user_id(int), milestone_id(int)
```

Milestones:

```
1 = Hired
2 = Promoted
3 = Moved to New Office
```

I want to count the number of `user_ids` which have records with `milestone_id = 1` and records with `milestone_id = 2`.

In other words, I want to see the number of users who have been both hired and promoted.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one method:

```
select um.user_id
from usermilestone um
where milestone_id in (1, 2)
group by um.user_id
having count(distinct um.milestone_id) = 2;
```

Comment: This is very useful. Thanks!